# JSON returning as [object Object] in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm a little green as you can tell by my post history here, but i am trying to get the key, value for a JSON object and its not outputting as i thought it would. What am I doing wrong?

```
(function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var tableRows = [];
        var headersText = [];
        var $headers = $("th");
        var $rows = $("#table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
          $cells = $(this).find("td");
          tableRows[index] = {};
          $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
            if(headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
              headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
            }
            tableRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(this).text();
          });    
        });
        var tableData = {
            "tableData": tableRows
        };
        /*alert(JSON.stringify(tableData));*/

        $.each([tableData], function(key, value){
            console.log( key + ":" + value );
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

in console I'm getting:

```
0:[object Object]
```

instead of (example):

```
0:[NAME SAMPLE-NAME]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't really the console.log, it's your iteration.

You mean to do this I think:

```
 $.each(tableData["tableData"], function(key, value){
      console.log( key, value );
 });
```

Not

```
 $.each([tableData], function(key, value){
      console.log( key, value );
 });
```

In your original code, you were creating an array of one element - `[tableData]` and then iterating over that, which doesn't really make any sense to do. TableData is a hash - a hash doesn't have a key and a value, it has a set of key and values. You need to iterate over the hash instead.

Comment: This worked, now how would i get for example the value of key: NAME in this object?

Comment: I think you're slightly confused over your data structure. You have 

`var tableData = {"tableData": tableRows};` but tableRows itself is an array. Is it possible that it's tableData["tableData"] that you want to iterate over?

Comment: yea thats it exactly. thanks for helping me learn :) so now i could console.log( key["NAME"], value ) to target that specifically?

Comment: Glad to help :) Let me know if there's any other questions you have.

Answer (score 5):

That's what happens when an object is turned into a string, and concantenating strings and objects, the object will be converted to a string, and the string representation of an object is `[object Object]`

```
console.log( key + ":" + value ); // you're concantenating strings and objects
```

Try this instead

```
console.log( key, value );
```

As a sitenote, `$.each` iterates both objects and arrays, so there's no need to wrap your object in an array, or your array in an object ?

Comment: Or `console.log({key:key,value:value})`

Comment: This worked, now how would i get for example the value of key: NAME in this object?

Comment: You'd have to know where that key was, and do something like `tableData.tableData.path.to.NAME`, or just iterate until you find it ?